# Reset password form wont update password

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
echo "You are logged in already. Try resetting your password instead.";
}else{

echo "

<html>

<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href='css/global.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<form method='POST' action='./resetpass.php'>
<table border='0' width='15%'>
<h3>Please enter your email so we can send you a link to reset your password.</h3>
<tr><td> Email Address: </td><td><input type='text' name='password' maxlength='40' placeholder=' Your Email Address' /></td></tr><br />
</table>
<p>
<input type='submit' value='Reset Password' /><br />
</form>

</html>

";
}
?>
<?php
include('fnc/connect.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = $_POST['password'];

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET password='23' ");


}else{
     echo "failed";
}

?>
```

But the code won't update the password in the database. Please ignore the "email" address in the HTML form as I copied it from another form for testing purposes. I just need to know why the text that I enter into the textbox won't update the current password in the database, but instead make it blanked out.

Thanks.

Comment: check your form action first than change your <input type="text"> to <input type="password">

Comment: @Vicky that wouldnt do anything except put a PasswordChar on the textbox would it? ill try it though....

Comment: i know i didn't provide the solution just corrected the error..

Comment: @Epodax its suppposed to be $email not 23, i set it back. it was for testing and stuff. I fixed the issue now with CoDe MurDeRers post.

Comment: All right, just wanted to let you know in case you had missed it, glad your issue got solved, remember to mark the answer as "Solved" then :)

Answer (score 3):

its because you miss to set name of submit button and you are trying to fetch is ..

replace this

```
<input type='submit' value='Reset Password' />
```

to this

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Reset Password' />
```